# Pandas read: multiple rows header as column names and different delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a text file with pandas.

The file has 7 columns of data. The header of each column is spread over multiple rows, from 3rd to 9th (first two rows are skipped). Data columns start at the 10th row.

| Row numbers are not in the file | File example (col1) | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | (skip) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2nd | (skip) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3rd | Apple, color white |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4th | Blue orange |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9th | Green banana |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10th | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 |
| 11th | 2.00 | 4.00 | 5.00 | 2.00 | 6.00 | 7.00 | 2.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

*Notice: data numbers have the same width. Data columns are separated by a white space.
I would like to assign the 3rd row to the 1st data column, 4th row to 2nd column, etc.

I tried `df = pd.read_fwf (filepath, widths=[5,...5], header=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`

expecting the row 3 to 9 being distributed as column names for my 7 data columns.

However, this gave me something similar to:

```
[]| Apple/Blue/Green/...|, col/orang/bana/...|or wh/e/na/...|ite/Unnamed: 3_level_1/Unnamed: 3_level_2/...|
0 |1.00|1.00|1.00|...|
1 |2.00|4.00|5.00|...|
```

Notice how all first 5 characters went into the 1st column name.

As opposed to what I would like:

```
[]| Apple, color white|Blue orange|Green banana|...|
0 |1.00|1.00|1.00|...|
1 |2.00|4.00|5.00|...|
```

I tried using `pd.read_table(fname, sep=' ', header=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`

but I keep having `IndexError: list index out of range` which I believe is because my header rows have white spaces and commas as opposed to my data columns that are exactly separated by white spaces.

Any tips on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: I have achieved the desired results with:  
`df = pd.read_table (fname, index_col=False, header=None, skiprows=2, nrows=7)`

`df_transposed = df.T`

`df1 = pd.read_table (fname, index_col=False, header=None, sep=' ', skiprows=9)`

`df1.columns = df_transposed.values.tolist()`

Comment: If there are any cleaner workarounds, I am still interested.